# OAuth2 Multiple Single User multiple Sign

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, spring-boot

Does OAuth2 support multiple sign in of the user from different devices at the same time? If yes, how can we make it happen?

Do we have to override the token generator and make changes there?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. Actually it doesn't care: The OAuth2 server will issue a new token on every sign-on, and all tokens are equally valid.

Comment: OK. But when the same user logs in from another device. I get an exception that says, more than one record found and does not provide a valid token.

Comment: Which specific OAuth2 server are you using?

Comment: I have my own custom OAuth2 server.

Comment: If you implemented it yourself, why aren't you in control of how many tokens per user you will support?

Comment: You are right. I just unable to figure out that part. Could you please direct me to some article? Searched a lot..but in vain.. Thanks

Comment: Asking google something like "implementing an oauth2 server" should give some readings. But I suspect your problem is maybe more relating to how you deal with tokens->user mappings internally, i.e. not related to OAuth2. Maybe if you could post some of the vital code here, I could help..?